# Coordinate Independence of Differential Forms Understanding

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

In *A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms* [Bachman, David], the author states the following:

(On the geometric interpretation of 1-forms in $\mathbb{R^2}$) - 'We can interpret the act of multiplying by a constant geometrically. Suppose $\mathbb{w}$ is given by $adx+bdy$. Then the value of $\mathbb{w}$(V1) is the length of the projection of V1 onto the line, $l$, where $\frac{<a,b>}{|<a,b>|^2}$ is a basis vector for $l$. This interpretation has a huge advantage... it is coordinate free. Forms are objects that exist independently of our choice of coordinates.'

I understand the geometric intuition, however, I fail to see why this is coordinate free. I would like to find out where I go wrong. What I see is that, as $\mathbb{w}$ relies on $dx$ and $dy$, the differentials of coordinate functions themselves, how can it then be coordinate free? Furthermore, in $\frac{<a,b>}{|<a,b>|^2}$, $<a.b>$ and thus its magnitude also depends on $dx$ and $dy$ so I fail to see how this is independent of coordinates - rather, the opposite as it makes an explicit reference to the differentials of coordinate functions?

Would be very grateful if someone can show me at what point my logic goes faulty...

Note: The author defines $dx$ and $dy$ as the coordinate function for $T_p\mathbb{R^2}$, such that a vector in $T_p\mathbb{R^2}$ can be written $<dx,dy>$ where $<1,0>=\frac{d(x+t,y)}{dt}$ and $<0,1>=\frac{d(x,y+t)}{dt}$

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507532/coordinate-independence-of-geometrical-objects

Comment: Not particularly

Comment: What works way better for me is to work with an abstract vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$. A 1-form $\theta$ is simply an element of $V^*$, which means a linear function on $V$. The level sets of a 1-form on a 2D vector space are parallel lines. Geometrically, the 1-form provides a "measuring stick". Given any vector $v$, $\theta(v)$ tells you which level set the end of $v$ touches. If you rescale the $1$-form, you're just rescaling the units of the measuring stick.

If you're not familiar with abstract vector spaces and their duals, you should try  reading about them first.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Like the link, I understand all of this, but my question is my lack of understanding in the way the book phrases it in the context. This is one part in how I am learning differential geometry, so am very keen to understand the book's conception of it!